# Change SharePoint 2010 WebfrontEnd server type to Application Server

Tags: sharepoint

I have add 4 servers to farm, 1 with central administration type. Have forgot to set Application servers roles for two servers. Need to change type of 2 servers to Application Servers. Is it possible or i need to remove them from farm and rejoin again with prior type?

Answer (score 1):

In SharePoint 2010, the only difference between a "Web Front-End" and "Application Server" is what services you enable on the server.  The bits installed are the same.

[Here is an MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc768569.aspx) on the services that you would enable/disable to differentiate them.